# Writing Windows applications with Swift

Tags: windows, swift, swift2

Is there a way to write Windows applications with Swift or Swift 2. I guess not but maybe you guys have a solution.

Comment: It's not possible yet.

Comment: https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-on-windows/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible yet because Swift isn't a Open Source.But later this year apple makes it open source so may there will be a way then.

Answer (score 1):

Use RemObjects Silver to write Windows application in Swift language via .Net platform.

Please note It's not a free solution like Xcode

Answer (score -2):

if you using mac, you can try using visual studio via virtualbox/vmware (tutorial here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj945492.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
or, you can develop universal windows platform using apache cordova first and debug it using visual studio on windows.
i know this is not absolute solution, but you can give it a try.

Comment: What has that to do with swift?